# Jquery returns NaN with price

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am trying to work out the total  price in jquery

I have try

**full jquery**

This is my jquery for changing the price in get_price i have a select statement an I am echoing the price `echo $row2['Price'];`

The way this works is that when every you change the `length` the price will change

so in pricetag you will get for an example `40.00` without the `£`

Comment: ... That is the credit crunch taking effect (or is it quantitative easing?)

Comment: Have you verified the result of `$('#pricetag').text()`? Of `parseInt()`? What is the `#pricetag` element? An input? If so, why aren't you using `.val()`? Have you done any basic debugging? Are you aware that we can't see your page?

Comment: What are the values of `$('#Qty').val();` and `$('#pricetag').text()` when this is called? The obvious answer to the question is: one of those two is not a number.

Comment: @MarkAmery `qty` will be number between 1-99 so like 1 or 2 or 3 or 10 `#pricetag` will be like 32.00 or 10.00 basically it will be a whole number and will end with `.00`

Comment: @SarahJames Well, `console.log` the actual values that you're dealing with in some case where you get NaN, and tell us what they are.

Comment: The code comment you added states: `will be somelike like £40.00`. What does that refer to? The result from `.text()`, or the final result?

Comment: Alright, the comment was moved out of the code. Now it appears as though `£40.00` is the result from `.text()`, and so there's your issue. The `£` character is not a valid number. Either remove it, or store the undecorated price in a `data-` attribute so you don't need to mess with display text to get your value.

Comment: `try var price = '\u00A3' + parseInt(document.getElementById('pricetag').innerHTML) * qty;`

Comment: @CrazyTrain pricetag holds a value for example 20.00 it all depends what  I am getting from the database but it will always be a `number.00`

Comment: But your updated question states that it will be something like `£40.00`

Comment: @CrazyTrain i said it depends it not always gonna be 40.00 or 32.00 it can be 10.00 NOTICE the `.00`

Comment: What is the 'pound' symbol doing there! Where is it coming from ? The DB ?

Comment: @SarahJames: Notice the ***`£`*** in your question. Is it going to be there, nor not. You're telling us two different things.

Comment: will price is gonna be something like 30.00 but the pound symbols will make it £30.00

Comment: What about using parseFloat()? Anybody mention this yet? You would obviously have to get rid of that pound sign.. Then add it again after I guess. But parseFloat will handle the `.` creating the NaN.

Comment: @SarahJames: Alright so the ***`£`*** *is* there. In that case, see [my previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775920/jquery-returns-nan-with-price#comment25926614_17775920)

Comment: @CrazyTrain i need the pound sign £ I cant use html pounds

Comment: @CrazyTrain Jesus, this comment thread is still going? That's nearly 20 minutes of your life you're not getting back, just because the OP *wouldn't answer simple questions* needed to solve her problem. You're feeding the help vampires, mate; give up and move on.

Comment: @SarahJames: Why can't you remove it before doing the math? Or why can't you do as I suggested above, and deliver the undecorated price as an attribute of the HTML element? The display can still keep the symbol.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Can you take this whole conversation and stick it into one simple answer for the girl? I don't think our comments are doing much for her.

Comment: @MarkAmery: Yeah, you're right. Just a shame that such a simple matter of clear communication is keeping OP from the solution.

Comment: I guess no one knows why :D lol 3 downvote but i dont see any those 3 people answering the question :). thanks guys for trying anyways

Comment: @SarahJames It's hard for us to answer the question when the question is not very specific (i.e. missing vital info), hence no one answers. Anyways, next time just include ALL the info so that we don't have to pry it out of you with a crowbar. As shown above we really TRIED to answer the question, the question just got in the way of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`#pricetag will be somelike like £40.00`" You need to get rid of the `£` in `#pricetag` before executing `parseInt()`. Something like this:

```
var price = '\u00A3' + (parseInt($('#pricetag').text().replace(/\u00A3/, ''), 10) * qty);
```

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) searches digits starting from the beginning of the string, and cuts the search at the first non-digit found. In your case the first character is `£`, so `parseFloat()` returns `NaN`, which produces `NaN` when used with `*`.

---

**EDIT**

What ever you have (or don't have anything) in front of the numbers in the `#pricetag`, you can use this to remove it:

```
var price = '\u00A3' + parseInt($('#pricetag').text().replace(/^\D/, ''), 10) * qty;
```

Also notice, that you have to validate `qty` *before* using it within calculations.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2jkv/2/).

Comment: @Teemu I fixed it... noob error where I had the price... I did `&pound;'.$row2['Price'].'` so the `&pound;` killed it

Comment: how can i do `&pound;'.$row2['Price'].'` without th pound sign getting in the way of the `'.$row2['Price'].'`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question, maybe give a bit more context to `&pound;'.$row2['Price'].`, like the corresponding HTML, and how you actually use that expression.

Comment: You've swapped over to PHP now?

Comment: @Teemu I am using ajax to check price based on what type of hair cut you are looking to have

in the price table i have it like 

 echo `echo '<td name="pricetag" class="pricetag" id="pricetag">'.$row2['Price'].'</td>';` which shows the first price for the basic hair style but as u change the style I use ajax to get the price of the style from a database and showing it

without me adding the the pound sign it will be just `30.00` how can i add the `£30.00` without it affect everything else

Comment: @SarahJames If I've understood your comment correctly, it doesn't matter, whether there's `£` or not in the `$('#pricetag').text()`. `replace()` will replace it with an empty string if it exists, otherways nothing is replaced. Please notice also what vpzomtrrfrt has said in his answer.

Comment: @Teemu `£` will only show in an `hidden div` I have which will show the total price. but without u clicking `the booking button` you shouldn't know if the price display is in pounds or dollars or whatever... so i need to show `£`

Comment: @SarahJames Please add the relevant code to your question. The lack of the information in the question was the reason for the downvotes at the first place, please don't collect more downvotes... If you mean there can be another non-digit character than `£` as a first character, you can replace `\u00A3` in the `replace()` with `\D`.

Comment: @Teemu I have updated the question with what i think is relevant

Comment: @SarahJames I'm not familiar with PHP, but `echo '&pound;' + $row2['Price']`?

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the edited version. seems u did that I did `echo 'pound;'.$row2['Price'].';`